# FindBugs IDEA - ClassNotFoundException com.google.wireless.android.sdk.stats.IntellijIndexingStats

Tags: android, findbugs

FindBugs IDEA v1.0.1
Android Studio 3.4

I get this error when running FindBugs.
I don't use com.google.wireless.android.sdk anywhere in the app.

```
Error:Internal error: (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException) com.google.wireless.android.sdk.stats.IntellijIndexingStats$Index
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.wireless.android.sdk.stats.IntellijIndexingStats$Index
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at com.intellij.util.indexing.counters.IndexCounters.<clinit>(IndexCounters.java:34)
    at com.intellij.util.indexing.impl.MapReduceIndex.<init>(MapReduceIndex.java:86)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.backwardRefs.index.CompilerReferenceIndex$CompilerMapReduceIndex.<init>(CompilerReferenceIndex.java:214)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.backwardRefs.index.CompilerReferenceIndex.<init>(CompilerReferenceIndex.java:73)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.backwardRefs.JavaCompilerBackwardReferenceIndex.<init>(JavaCompilerBackwardReferenceIndex.java:12)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.backwardRefs.JavaBackwardReferenceIndexWriter.initialize(JavaBackwardReferenceIndexWriter.java:74)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.backwardRefs.JavaBackwardReferenceIndexBuilder.buildStarted(JavaBackwardReferenceIndexBuilder.java:40)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuild(IncProjectBuilder.java:358)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.build(IncProjectBuilder.java:178)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.runBuild(BuildRunner.java:138)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:302)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:135)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:229)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl.lambda$executeOnPooledThread$0(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: @Carlton Yes, I switched to spotbugs.

Comment: think it's this [plugin](https://github.com/JetBrains/android); there's at least `com.google.wireless.android.sdk.stats` involved.

Comment: This error occurred for me after upgrading to Android Studio 3.4. Did you have a similar experience?

Comment: The bug appeared when i switched to Android Studio 3.4

Comment: related github issues

Comment: https://github.com/mapbox/store-locator-android/issues/27

Comment: https://github.com/spotbugs/spotbugs/issues/931

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this may be the answer.

SpotBugs is the spiritual successor of FindBugs, carrying on from the point where it left off with support of its community.

[The FindBugs Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/findbugs_plugin.html)

> Since FindBugs is unmaintained and does not support bytecode compiled for Java 9 and above, the FindBugs plugin has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 6.0. Please consider using the [SpotBugs plugin](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.github.spotbugs) instead.

[You should have at least 512 MB of memory](https://spotbugs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html) to use SpotBugs. To analyze very large projects, more memory may be needed.

Very important issue [Unable to use Spotbugs in Android application](https://github.com/spotbugs/spotbugs-gradle-plugin/issues/90).

Comment: I tried searching for SpotBugs in the Marketplace inside the settings dialog and nothing came back.

Answer (score 43):

To Solve this problem in Android Studio go to:

File
-> Settings
-> Build, Execution, Deployment
-> Compiler
-> Java Compiler

Change `javac` to `eclipse`, and apply.

Comment: any explanation about that ?

Comment: This is no longer an option on AS

Comment: I tried this option in AS 4.0.1, the error gone but other appears: Error:Module 'MyModule' production: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/resources/ResourceFolderType

Comment: on MacOS it's under Android Studio -> Preferences

Answer (score 17):

For what it's worth i got this exact error by importing a project started with IntelliJ Pro and imported into Android Studio - deleting the `.idea` directory at the root of the project and re-importing the project with Android Studio cleared it.

Answer (score 4):

open the FindBugs setting, click General,then close the "Compile affected files before analyze". It works for me with Android Studio 3.5

Answer (score 2):

I got this error in Android Studio without running FindBugs.

I initially saw [an IntelliJ post](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-221848) suggesting I disable compiler-based indexing in the IntelliJ registry to stop the error:

> as a workaround for the exception you may set `compiler.ref.index = false` in Registry (ctrl+alt-shift+/ or via "find action by name" action)

However, I didn't want to settle for losing compiler-based indexing, after doing an `Invalidate Caches / Restart...`, I saw the following message:

```
Internal caches are corrupted or have outdated format, forcing project rebuild
```

That message led me to [pdinklag's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25279141/9636), which I [modified slightly for Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58598949/9636)

I shut down Android Studio, then ran:

```
rm -rf ~/.android
rm -rf <PROJECT_ROOT>/.idea
```

Then restarted Android Studio, and things worked.

Answer (score 1):

This removed the error for me:

File/Settings/Build, Execution, Deployment/Compiler

uncheck: Make project automatically

Comment: Its worked for me, thanks. I'm use Android Studio 4.0

Answer (score 0):

Seems that FindBugs is not able to compile the files before analyze.

In Android Studio, go to FindBugs settings (found under File > Settings > Other Settings), and UNCHECK "Compile affected files before analyze".

When you do this, then you need to compile files yourself (by building and running the app, for example), or FindBugs analyze uses old file data (from the previous build).

Answer (score -2):

This solution is based on the assumption that You use Android Studio for Flutter and Android both. Each time I close Flutter project and open up Android project I need to configure android Sdk else it gives me this error:

```
Error:Internal error: (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException) 
com.google.wireless.android.sdk.stats.IntellijIndexingStats$Index
```

Simply go to the LogCat and Click on the "Please configure Android SDK" and select the latest Build Tools Version 28.0.3 I guess( or whatever is your latest build version) from the dropdown.

Comment: This is weird: I found a page explaining Android Studio "Logcat" (https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat) but it's not listed in View > Tool Windows > Logcat

Answer (score -2):

I faced similar error with JDK 1.8. The error was caused by a missing keystore file. Try generating new keystore using a keytool from JDK 12. This worked for me.

Also add some dependencies and maven repositories according to yout gradle version may be also need to 
AndroidAnnotations version:

4.3.1

Android compile SDK version:

25