# Cannot build empty flutter project with intellij or android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, flutter

I have been coding kotlin in intellij to develop an app for android but then found out about flutter and wanted to give it a try. Installed flutter sdk and flutter and dart plugins ok. Now even the default empty demo project runs in both my phone and in emulator but i can't build it and cannot generate an apk. I have also downloaded the android studio to try with it but a similar error occurs in it too.

Searched all the web for a solution.

```
ERROR IN THE INTELLIJ

Error:Internal error: (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException) javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:436)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:157)
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:76)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:82)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.android.AndroidJpsUtil.getAndroidTarget(AndroidJpsUtil.java:405)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.android.AndroidJpsUtil.getAndroidPlatform(AndroidJpsUtil.java:481)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.android.builder.AndroidPreDexBuildTarget.computeRootDescriptors(AndroidPreDexBuildTarget.java:111)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.builders.impl.BuildRootIndexImpl.addRoots(BuildRootIndexImpl.java:72)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.builders.impl.BuildRootIndexImpl.<init>(BuildRootIndexImpl.java:62)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.load(BuildRunner.java:85)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:265)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:121)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:228)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)

ERROR IN THE ANDROID STUDIO

Error:Internal error: (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException) com.google.wireless.android.sdk.stats.IntellijIndexingStats$Index
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.wireless.android.sdk.stats.IntellijIndexingStats$Index
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:436)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at com.intellij.util.indexing.counters.IndexCounters.<clinit>(IndexCounters.java:34)
    at com.intellij.util.indexing.impl.MapReduceIndex.<init>(MapReduceIndex.java:85)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.backwardRefs.index.CompilerReferenceIndex$CompilerMapReduceIndex.<init>(CompilerReferenceIndex.java:232)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.backwardRefs.index.CompilerReferenceIndex.<init>(CompilerReferenceIndex.java:79)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.backwardRefs.JavaCompilerBackwardReferenceIndex.<init>(JavaCompilerBackwardReferenceIndex.java:12)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.backwardRefs.JavaBackwardReferenceIndexWriter.initialize(JavaBackwardReferenceIndexWriter.java:79)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.buildStarted(JavaBuilder.java:148)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuild(IncProjectBuilder.java:363)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.build(IncProjectBuilder.java:178)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.runBuild(BuildRunner.java:139)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:302)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:135)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:228)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl.lambda$executeOnPooledThread$0(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:42)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
```

Comment: Did you check https://stackoverflow.com/a/55936104/104891? Does it help?

Comment: I didn't install findbugs or spotbugs plugins. I am just trying to build a plain empty demo project which has a button and a counter that counts how many times you pressed the button. Only installed plugins are flutter and dart.

Comment: try using vscode

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll try vscode and return the result here.

Comment: Thanks G griffo! I was able to build an apk with vscode. But it would be better to use IntelliJ. I was used to it. Anyone knows why AS and IntelliJ can not build? Can it be a bug?

Comment: Another question: How can i sign the apk i create and make use of proguard within vscode?