# Can't build android app due to ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android, android-studio, tensorflow, android-sdk-tools

The project I try to build:
 https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/image_classification/android

The configuration of my Android studio:
Project SDK: Android API 29 (Java version 1.8.0_202)
Project language level: 8
Project compiler output: set
No extra libraries
Nothing under the Problems tab in Project Structure

The error itself is the following:

```
 Error:Internal error: (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException) com.google.wireless.android.sdk.stats.IntellijIndexingStats$Index
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.wireless.android.sdk.stats.IntellijIndexingStats$Index
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at com.intellij.util.indexing.counters.IndexCounters.<clinit>(IndexCounters.java:34)
    at com.intellij.util.indexing.impl.MapReduceIndex.<init>(MapReduceIndex.java:85)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.backwardRefs.index.CompilerReferenceIndex$CompilerMapReduceIndex.<init>(CompilerReferenceIndex.java:232)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.backwardRefs.index.CompilerReferenceIndex.<init>(CompilerReferenceIndex.java:79)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.backwardRefs.JavaCompilerBackwardReferenceIndex.<init>(JavaCompilerBackwardReferenceIndex.java:12)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.backwardRefs.JavaBackwardReferenceIndexWriter.initialize(JavaBackwardReferenceIndexWriter.java:79)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.buildStarted(JavaBuilder.java:148)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuild(IncProjectBuilder.java:363)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.build(IncProjectBuilder.java:178)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.runBuild(BuildRunner.java:139)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:302)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:135)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:228)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl.lambda$executeOnPooledThread$0(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The only similar question that I found was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55844077/findbugs-idea-classnotfoundexception-com-google-wireless-android-sdk-stats-int), although it didn't help since I don't use FindBugs

[Part of the full log.](https://pastebin.com/0JwtjRbV)

About
Build version: Android Studio 3.5.3 Build #AI-191.8026.42.35.6010548 November 15, 2019
Java version: 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03amd64
Operating System: Windows 10 (10.0, amd64)
JVM version: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM JetBrains s.r.o

System
Number of CPU: 8
Used memory: 156Mb 
Free memory: 173Mb 
Total memory: 329Mb 
Maximum available memory:

Plugins
[Dart (191.8593), Flutter (42.1.1)]
Disabled plugins:[]

Comment: Does the issue occur in IntelliJ IDEA as well (you've tagged your question with `#intellij-idea`)? Full logs may provide more clues (Help | Compress Logs and Show in ...).

Comment: Nope I mistakenly used the tag.

Comment: @CrazyCoder ok I created a pastepin with the resent logs. Could it be due to some Flutter plugins that I used for a previous project?

Comment: Does it help if you add `-Dcompiler.ref.index=false` in Help | Edit Custom VM Options and restart the IDE?

Comment: Yes! that did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [related issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-221848) logged in IDEA project.

While this bug is specific to Android Studio as it's using the modified version of `MapReduceIndex`, the workaround suggested in the comments should help.

Add the following in Help | Edit Custom VM Options:

```
-Dcompiler.ref.index=false
```

Restart the IDE.