# Android Studio Stuck at √ Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk. while building flutter app into android device

Tags: java, android, android-studio, flutter, dart

Android Studio Stuck at √ Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk. while building flutter app into android device. I'm using Oppo F9 Mobile.

This was the errors shown in problem option in the Android Studio

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.wireless.android.sdk.stats.IntellijIndexingStats$Index
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at com.intellij.util.indexing.counters.IndexCounters.<clinit>(IndexCounters.java:34)
    at com.intellij.util.indexing.impl.MapReduceIndex.<init>(MapReduceIndex.java:94)
    at com.intellij.util.indexing.impl.MapReduceIndex.<init>(MapReduceIndex.java:110)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.backwardRefs.index.CompilerReferenceIndex$CompilerMapReduceIndex.<init>(CompilerReferenceIndex.java:248)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.backwardRefs.index.CompilerReferenceIndex.<init>(CompilerReferenceIndex.java:84)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.backwardRefs.JavaCompilerBackwardReferenceIndex.<init>(JavaCompilerBackwardReferenceIndex.java:12)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.backwardRefs.JavaBackwardReferenceIndexWriter.initialize(JavaBackwardReferenceIndexWriter.java:80)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.buildStarted(JavaBuilder.java:149)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuild(IncProjectBuilder.java:359)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.build(IncProjectBuilder.java:178)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.runBuild(BuildRunner.java:139)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:288)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:121)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:228)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

this is where it is stuck in Android Studio

```
Launching lib\main.dart on CPH1823 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
√ Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.
```

Android Studio Version

```
Android Studio 3.6.1
Build #AI-192.7142.36.36.6241897, built on February 27, 2020
Runtime version: 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 1246M
Cores: 4
Registry: ide.new.welcome.screen.force=true
Non-Bundled Plugins: CMD Support, QAPlug, QAPlug - FindBugs, cn.renyuzhuo.plugin.easygradle, com.herbert.george.flutter-snippets, importre.intellij.android.selector, net.masterthought.dlanguage, org.dlangplugin, GradleDependenciesHelper, com.github.platan.gradle-dependencies-formatter, com.github.shiraji.gradleconfirmation, cn.bestwu.gdph, com.google.services.firebase, me.scana.okgradle, Dart, io.flutter, de.mariushoefler.flutter_enhancement_suite
```

Comment: this solution will solve your issue. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59547929/8035260

Comment: i tried it before asking this question and it did not work for me. my other project works fine and easily get installed in my device but my other project just show the app in my device and for some reason close the app. and then it wont open the app. and it get stuck on √ Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.

Comment: In my logcat it is showing this error... what is it?
E/WifiVendorHal: getWifiLinkLayerStats(l.947) failed {.code = ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED, .description = }

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but flutter clean (Tools/Flutter/Flutter Clean) and deleting the cache folder of the gradle (/Users//.gradle/caches/modules-2/<metadata-folder(s)>) helped me.