# Android Studio Version 3.6.2 Error with IntellijIndexingStats$Index

Tags: android

When I try to run my app, I get this error:

```
Error:Internal error: (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException) com.google.wireless.android.sdk.stats.IntellijIndexingStats$Index
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.wireless.android.sdk.stats.IntellijIndexingStats$Index
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at com.intellij.util.indexing.counters.IndexCounters.<clinit>(IndexCounters.java:34)
at com.intellij.util.indexing.impl.MapReduceIndex.<init>(MapReduceIndex.java:94)
at com.intellij.util.indexing.impl.MapReduceIndex.<init>(MapReduceIndex.java:110)
at org.jetbrains.jps.backwardRefs.index.CompilerReferenceIndex$CompilerMapReduceIndex.<init>(CompilerReferenceIndex.java:248)
at org.jetbrains.jps.backwardRefs.index.CompilerReferenceIndex.<init>(CompilerReferenceIndex.java:84)
at org.jetbrains.jps.backwardRefs.JavaCompilerBackwardReferenceIndex.<init>(JavaCompilerBackwardReferenceIndex.java:12)
at org.jetbrains.jps.backwardRefs.JavaBackwardReferenceIndexWriter.initialize(JavaBackwardReferenceIndexWriter.java:80)
at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.buildStarted(JavaBuilder.java:149)
at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuild(IncProjectBuilder.java:359)
at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.build(IncProjectBuilder.java:178)
at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.runBuild(BuildRunner.java:139)
at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:288)
at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:121)
at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:228)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

In project structure -> Project Settings -> Project ->  I have YOUR_PROJECT_PATH/ out as my project compiler output.

In project structure -> Project Settings -> Module -> inherit project compile output path is checked.

What should I change?

Comment: Check : https://stackoverflow.com/q/55844077/2641657