# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.wireless.android.sdk.stats.IntellijIndexingStats$Index

Tags: java, android, module, classnotfoundexception

When I'm trying to Make Module in order to build my project I'm getting the

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.wireless.android.sdk.stats.IntellijIndexingStats$Index error
```

I've tried what it says on this posts, but with no success:

https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Unity-SDK/issues/162

[FindBugs IDEA - ClassNotFoundException com.google.wireless.android.sdk.stats.IntellijIndexingStats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55844077/findbugs-idea-classnotfoundexception-com-google-wireless-android-sdk-stats-int)

```
Information:12-May-19 3:22 PM - Compilation completed with 1 error and 0 warnings in 1 s 703 ms
Error:Internal error: (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException) com.google.wireless.android.sdk.stats.IntellijIndexingStats$Index
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.wireless.android.sdk.stats.IntellijIndexingStats$Index
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at com.intellij.util.indexing.counters.IndexCounters.<clinit>(IndexCounters.java:34)
    at com.intellij.util.indexing.impl.MapReduceIndex.<init>(MapReduceIndex.java:86)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.backwardRefs.index.CompilerReferenceIndex$CompilerMapReduceIndex.<init>(CompilerReferenceIndex.java:214)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.backwardRefs.index.CompilerReferenceIndex.<init>(CompilerReferenceIndex.java:73)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.backwardRefs.JavaCompilerBackwardReferenceIndex.<init>(JavaCompilerBackwardReferenceIndex.java:12)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.backwardRefs.JavaBackwardReferenceIndexWriter.initialize(JavaBackwardReferenceIndexWriter.java:74)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.backwardRefs.JavaBackwardReferenceIndexBuilder.buildStarted(JavaBackwardReferenceIndexBuilder.java:40)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuild(IncProjectBuilder.java:358)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.build(IncProjectBuilder.java:178)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.runBuild(BuildRunner.java:138)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:302)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:135)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:229)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl.lambda$executeOnPooledThread$0(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: did you fixed it ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/57957836/9481500
Also, this is probably duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/57957836

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing the same issue (and completely new to android studio)
This is the steps I followed when i was trying to create my own WA stickers:

download Android Studio 3.6.3 (installed using default settings on WIndows system)

- From Android Studio, New -> Project from Version Control -> Git ->
  https://github.com/WhatsApp/stickers
- With the example project loaded, attempt to compile via "Build" ->
  Make module "main"
- I also installed the "Findbug" plugin mentioned @MarvinJWendt via
  File -> Settings -> Plugins -> "QAPlug - FindBugs".

Also, both v1.0 and v1.1 of "SpotBug" from https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/14014-spotbugs is not compatible with the Android Studio version I have.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Jar file conflict. If you are using IDE like idea. You can try a plugin named Maven Helper to find out which dependence rise up this
>    error.
> 2. ClassLoader issue. I think the URLClassLoader not work well with your project's default ClassLoader. I mean URLClassLoader usually use
>    to load the external java code, its class path is different.